# Best company for flying from Europe to Australia

Tags: europe, airlines, australia, korean-air

Me and my wife are planning a journey to Australia next March. We live in Madrid, Spain, and we would like to know which is the best company for flying to Australia (Melburne or Sydney).

We are actually considering:
- Emirates
- Qatar
- Korean Air

Can somebody help us decide?

Comment: Hi Samuel, Welcome to Travel.se. Could you be a little more specific  with your questions, what do you mean by 'best airline'? Cheapest, quickest, most comfortable?

Comment: Samuel, as Stuart implies, 'best' is very subjective - we want questions that we can answer objectively.  Are you looking for the one with the top safety record, or the cheapest, or with the most onboard movies? Please reword and then we can happily help find you an answer :)

Comment: Emirates seems to be a much praised airline but I've never flown them. I did recently start doing quite a few miles with Korean though and I'm so impressed they are now my favourite airline. Very easy and flexible date changes, good in flight meals, and I love the stopovers in Korea on my way to and way back from Europe - they're free!

Answer (score 1):

I flew from Australia to Europe with [Singapore Airlines](http://www.singaporeair.com/) and they were fine - good price and good service on board. They were also quite helpful when we discovered one piece of our luggage had been damaged and gave us the necessary paperwork for claiming back the cost of repair. I've heard good reports about Emirates but haven't flown with them myself. Qantas have been a bit in the wars lately with various safety issues. I guess it also depends on what you're after in terms of service (economy?), stop overs etc.